# Check time every 5 minutes and compare it to button's time - Android

Tags: java, android, button

I have a class called EventButton which extends Button.

All of the Button's settings are in this class, onClick() etc.

I also have a Home activity which has a scrollview

The EventButtons are added to the Home activity's scroll view when the user presses a menu button. I don't instantiate an  object I just call new EventButton()

When the user clicks on the button a dialog is displayed and the user set's the name of the "Event" and time of the "Event".

The name and time are then displayed on that button inside the scollview on the home activity.

My question is, how would you go about refreshing the EventButton every, say, 5 minutes to check if the time set on it has passed. I have tried a TimerTask and Timer and also a Handler but neither seem to work. The TimerTask kept crashing, I also found out that it's better to use Handler in android.

```
    private void scheduleDelay() {

    EventButton.this.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int mHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int mMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            if(EventButton.hour < mHour || EventButton.minute < mMinute) {
                EventButton.this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            EventButton.this.postDelayed(this, 5);
        }
    }, 5);
}
```

The above is called when the user sets the name and time of the EventButton in the AlertDialog.

**Update**

The problem doesn't seem to be with the Handler after all. It seems to be when I try to get the hour and minute that it's crashing.

Comment: *"I don't instantiate an object I just call new EventButton()"* Isn't that the same?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that's my bad. I'm basically trying to say that I'm not creating EventButton objects to be manipulated in the Home class. I'm using a loop and just calling new EventButton on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Change your usage to be 5 minutes (5 * 60 * 1000) not 5 milliseconds:

```
private void scheduleDelay() {

    EventButton.this.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int mHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int mMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            if(EventButton.hour < mHour || EventButton.minute < mMinute) {
                EventButton.this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                // wait another 5 minutes
                scheduleDelay();
            }

        }
    }, 300000);
}
```

Comment: I had it on 5 milliseconds for testing purposes, didn't want to be waiting 5 minutes to see if it worked or not. It still didn't work on 5 milliseconds though, so I presume it wouldn't work after 5 minutes?